# List Index Out Of Range In Vice Versa

Tags: python, list, indexing

i'm a beginner in python and not allowed to import external modules to assist my work, and i'm having trouble with list index. So, i'm running a few test lines to figure this out (Line 8 to 11). Note that line 10 can output normally, while vice versa line 11 throws an error. Also, line 12 throws an error, but similar code in line 17 works just fine.

```
search_keyword = input() # Asks for patient's name or id  (either one), if patient's name or id exists in database, output display other details such as Age, Group & Zone.
with open("database.txt", "r") as database:
     for data in database:
         for patients in data.split('|'):
             patient_details = []
             for details in patients.split(','):
                 patient_details.append(details)
             print(patient_details) # test
             print(len(patient_details) # test
             print(patient_details.index('ATO1A')) # test
             print(patient_details[4]) # test
             if search_keyword == patient_details[0] or search_keyword == patient_details[4]: # error occured here, where it says list index out of range.
                        print("Name: " + patient_details[0])
                        print("Group: " + patient_details[1])
                        print("Zone: " + patient_details[2])
                        print("Phone Number: " + patient_details[3])
                        print("ID: " + patient_details[4]) # no error here, patient_details[4] is able to display patient's id
```

database.txt

```
NICK,ATO,A,01123381633,ATO1A,POSITIVE,Not Required,Not Required,C1,ACTIVE|MAX,AHS,F,01123361633,AHS2F,NEGATIVE,To Be Determined,To Be Determined,,|JOHN,SID,F,01123331333,SID3F,NEGATIVE,To Be Determined,To Be Determined,,|ZOFIA,AHD,C,01123341633,AHD4C,POSITIVE,Not Required,Not Required,C2,ACTIVE|
```

Test command for line 8,9, 10 and 11:

```
Line 8: [NICK, ATO, A, 01123381633, ATO1A, POSITIVE, Not Required, Not Required, C1, ACTIVE]
Line 9: 10
Line 10: 4
Line 11: IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can someone explain why this is happening, and any solutions regarding this issue without using any imported modules? Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: You have a missing close parentheses at line 9. When I add it, I don't get an IndexError, tho...

Comment: Hi Wesley - if you can post a more comprehensive dataset, it will improve the odds of getting a good answer. Beyond that, relying on fixed indices generally isn't safe, especially if you know not all records will have all fields. 

You may want to incorporate checks on the length of patient_details, or use a try / except block to log out the actual rows of your data and examine what's actually in the list, thus improving your ability to debug the code.

Comment: I agree with jrjames83. Did some testing and I think the problem is in your dataset, I guess you only shared a part of it but has actually more than two entries, and some of these don't have 4 commas.

Comment: Alright, thanks guys! I will look it up.

Comment: @bitomic I've updated the database of mine with 4 entries

Comment: @Wesley - would you mind formatting your dataset so each record is on a separate row? Feel free to use gist.github.com and post the link, happy to look at it later today at lunch and provide some feedback and example code you can run with.